# laravel - count records from many tables using condition whereBetween

Tags: mysql, ajax, laravel-8

```php
function fetch_c(Request $request) {
    if($request->ajax()) {
       if($request->from_date != '' && $request->to_date != '') {
           return $request;
         $data = DB::select("SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pos) as a, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM customers) as b, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM supplires) as c") 
         ->whereBetween('created_at', array($request->from_date, $request->to_date));
        }
       else {
           $data = DB::select("SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pos) as a, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM customers) as b, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM supplires) as c");
       }

       echo json_encode($data); 
   }    
}
```

Comment: $data = DB::select("SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pos) as a, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM customers) as b, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM supplires) as c")
         ->whereBetween('created_at', array($request->from_date, $request->to_date));
        }

Comment: I think you should remove `return $request;` statement in `if` clause.

Comment: yes i remove but not working

Comment: GET http://localhost:8000/fetch_c?from_date=2022-03-30&to_date=2022-03-30 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: how to slove this error and fetch count many table with condition whereBetween

Comment: how to slove..??